# How many time performFetchWithCompletionHandler gave to the app to process everything?

Tags: ios, background-fetch

I don't understand, in the doc about `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` they say:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623125-application

> your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to perform the
>   download operation and call the specified completion handler block

but in the code i do like this

```
performFetchWithCompletionHandler 
  beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler
  sleep 4 min
  Logn(...)
  CompletionHandler
  endBackgroundTask
  Logn(...)
```

and it's work fine ! the app is alive still the end (4 min in all) and I can see the log in the monitor ... I just have several time a call of the `ExpirationHandler` given to `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` but it's no matter the app is still alive and working

what did I miss ? so how many time we have to process everything ?